# _CF_forwarding_prep_0 Crash on app run (iPad)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, crash, exc-bad-access

My app is crash on iPad launch, but works normally on iPhone.
I already tried to add a `Symbolic breakpoint` to `-[UIView(Hierarchy) setNeedsLayout]` but I didn't found what is causing this.

Stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180354bec lookUpImpOrForward + 136
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18035f258 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 56
2  UIKit                          0x1877679c4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) setNeedsLayout] + 196
3  UIKit                          0x187a420ac __UIViewNoteTraitsDidChangeRecursively + 292
4  UIKit                          0x187a421d0 __UIViewNoteTraitsDidChangeRecursively + 584
5  UIKit                          0x187a421d0 __UIViewNoteTraitsDidChangeRecursively + 584
6  UIKit                          0x187a421d0 __UIViewNoteTraitsDidChangeRecursively + 584
7  UIKit                          0x187a421d0 __UIViewNoteTraitsDidChangeRecursively + 584
8  UIKit                          0x187a421d0 __UIViewNoteTraitsDidChangeRecursively + 584
9  UIKit                          0x187a421d0 __UIViewNoteTraitsDidChangeRecursively + 584
10 UIKit                          0x187a421d0 __UIViewNoteTraitsDidChangeRecursively + 584
11 UIKit                          0x187ab84a0 -[UIViewController _updateTraitsIfNecessary] + 312
12 UIKit                          0x1877533e0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 832
13 QuartzCore                     0x184c1b40c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
14 QuartzCore                     0x184c100e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
15 QuartzCore                     0x184c0ffa8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
16 QuartzCore                     0x184b8cc64 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
17 QuartzCore                     0x184bb40d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
18 QuartzCore                     0x184bb4af0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1818c17dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1818bf40c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1818bf89c __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1817ee048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
23 GraphicsServices               0x183271198 GSEventRunModal + 180
24 UIKit                          0x1877c1628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
25 UIKit                          0x1877bc360 UIApplicationMain + 208
26 MyApp                          0x10006c730 main (AppDelegate.swift:34)
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x1807d05b8 (Missing)
```

On Crashlytics I have different titles for the same crash, such as:

`-[NSConcreteMapTable setNeedsLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17fbdca0`

`-[_NSConcreteObservation setNeedsLayout]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170235da0`

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000e9c2cbeb8`

Is there another way to debug and figure out what is happening?